# How I can get the changed value after onclick in React 15?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Problem: Using the onClick method, I want the openModal property in the madule.js component to be set to true and I can get its changed value in the modifier.js component, but after onClick, the value changes in madule.js, but I can't get the updated value in modifier.js get :(

Description: We have two components called madule.js and modifier.js. I want the openModal property, which was false in its initial value, to be true when the onClick method was called in the module component. For this, I defined the onAdd method and put openModal = true there and put it as an output in the return of the getOpenModal function and then stored this function inside the OpenModal variable and returned it.
I received the OpenModal in the modifier.js component by using @ connect defined in Redux, but after the onClick method is called in the module component, I cannot receive the updated value in the modifier component.
What solution do you suggest so that I can get the changed value after onclick in the madule.js component?

***Modifier.js Component***

```
import React from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

@autobind
@authorize
@connect(
  (state) => ({

    openModal: state.Attendance.Reports.columns,
 
  }),
 
)
@autobind
/**
 *
 */
export default class Modifier extends React.PureComponent {
  static propTypes = {

    openModal: PropTypes.array,
  };

  /**
   *
   * @param {Object} props
   */
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {

    const { openModal } = this.props;

    if(openModal){
      console.log("true ");//after onClick in module.js ,openModal dose not change to true
    }else{
      console.log("false");
    }

    return (
      <>{openModal}</>
    );
  }
}
```

Module.js Component

```
import React from "react";

// -------------------------------------------------------------------< constants >-------------------------------------------------------------------

const INDEX_ATTENDANCE_REPORT_SUCCESS = "INDEX_ATTENDANCE_REPORT_SUCCESS";



/**
 *
 * @param {Array} dataTable
 * @return {Array}
 */
 export function getOpenModal(dataTable) {
    let column={value:"Personnel ID"}
    let openModal = false;
    const onAdd = () => {
      openModal = true;
    };
  
      if (
        column.value === "Personnel ID" 
      ) {
        return (
          <a
            onClick={() => onAdd()}
            style={{ color: "red", cursor: "pointer" }}
          >
            {text}
          </a>
        );
      } 
    return openModal;
  }




// --------------------------------------------------------------------< reducer >--------------------------------------------------------------------
/**
 *
 * @param {object} state
 * @param {object} action
 * @return {object}
 */
export default function reducer(
  state = {
    openModal: [],
  },
  action
) {
  let openModal = [];
  switch (action.type) {

    case INDEX_ATTENDANCE_REPORT_SUCCESS:
        openModal = getOpenModal(action.payload.data);
      return Object.assign({}, state, {
        openModal,
      });
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```